# how to get wp include directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to do require_once for my wp plugin development. It seems to me that I need to use absolute path.

my current solution is

```
$delimiter = strpos(dirname(__FILE__), "/")!==false?"/":"\\"; //win or unix?
$path = explode($delimiter,  dirname(__FILE__));

require_once join(array_slice($path,0,count($path)-3),$delimiter) . "/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php";
```

**I wonder if there is a better way to handle this, kind of general approach.**

What if the wp plugin directory structure changes. So this part `count($path)-3` won't be valid any more ....

Comment: Where is this wp-include dir located on the dashboard? I am trying to find the header.php file and read that it would be in this directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
require_once realpath(__DIR__.'/../../..').'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
```

Or replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)` if you are on < PHP 5.3

Or you could try:

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php';
```

Comment: /../../.. or count($path)-3 is kind of the same. I thought there might be better solution using some of wordpress functions that would return the path....

Comment: I don't know how WP works, but the defacto standard is to set a constant when you first load the application to the root path of the application then use that every where else.

Comment: my point is that `/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` is wordpress include path. What you suggest is how to handle plugin development. My question is how to be `independent` on wordpress file structure changes. Probably I can't be :-)

Answer (score 23):

WordPress establishes the path to the includes directory on startup.

`require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/your-file.php';`

Comment: +1 for knowing about ABSPATH. Unfortunately, it doesn't use it consistently and usually uses a relative or absolute path when linking. It is a major pain if you want to change the directory name for security.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to take advantage of WP_CONTENT_DIR and make a nice constant

```
define(WP_INCLUDE_DIR, preg_replace('/wp-content$/', 'wp-includes', WP_CONTENT_DIR));
```

or a function

```
function wp_include_dir(){
    $wp_include_dir = preg_replace('/wp-content$/', 'wp-includes', WP_CONTENT_DIR));
    return $wp_include_dir;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing bloginfo('wpurl') / wp-content/plugins ?

Comment: yes, I was looking into this one. It won't provide path to `wp-admin/includes`. There are also includes in `wp-includes` so it is bit confusing. My thought here is on how to be independent on wordpress file structure changes.

Answer (score 2):

I used to define it as a constant, like the others ...

```
if(defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR') && !defined('WP_INCLUDE_DIR')){
   define('WP_INCLUDE_DIR', str_replace('wp-content', 'wp-includes', WP_CONTENT_DIR));
}
```

One still could check with `is_dir()` and traverse further, if required.